# Hermitian Matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics, hermitian-matrices

Given
$ \begin{equation*}
Y = 
\begin{pmatrix}
y & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -iy \\
0 & iy & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$

Given another matrix $X$ which has two degenerate eigenvalues and commutes with $Y$, that is $XY = YX$. Can we claim anything about $X$ in general, more specifically if $X$ is Hermitian or not. I used commutative property to find $X$ as

$ \begin{equation*}
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & ci & c \\
-mi & t & -n \\
m & n & t 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$

But I can' use the property that $X$ has two degenerate eigenvalues.
Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "degenerate eigenvalues" in this context?

Comment: I just mean that out of three eigenvalues of X (in complex number set) two of the Eigenvalues are equal, like  z, ,z, z' are the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

No $X$ need not be Hermitian. Given any Hermitian matrix $X$ satisfying the constraints in the question, we define $X' = i X$. Then $X'$ also satisfies all constraints in the question but is not Hermitian.

But let's investigate $X$ further. Working in the orthonormal basis in which $Y$ is diagonal we have
$$
Y = \begin{pmatrix} y & 0 & 0 \\
0 & y & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -y 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then by the commutation constraint $X$ needs to be of the form
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix} 
x_{00} & x_{01} & 0 \\
x_{10} & x_{11} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & x_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But now take the top left block to be any $2\times 2$ matrix that has two distinct eigenvalues. If we pick $x_{22}$ equal to one of those eigenvalues then we satisfy the constraints in the question. This shows that $X$ need not even be normal as we can pick the top left block to be a non-normal matrix.

Comment: Actually I have to find X in same basis as Y so diagonalization may not be a good approach. Or maybe we can find X and revert it back to original basis using similarity transformation.

Comment: @MayankJha Exactly, you can just write $X$ in whatever basis you want. This does not affect commutativity or the eigenvalues.

Comment: How do we guess the transformation matrix from one basis to another? Is there any method to calculate it, or is it just brute force multiplication?

Comment: You need to work out the spectral decomposition of $Y$. This gives you $Y=UDU^*$ where $U$ is the change of basis unitary matrix and $D$ is the diagonal form of $Y$. So once you have $X$ in that basis you can change back to the original basis by $UXU^*$.

Comment: Ya I was asking about U, that how do we guess this matrix. It's Unitary gives us a condition. And do we use brute force multiplication to find the matrix U completely?

Comment: $U$ is the matrix where the $k$-th column is the eigenvector corresponding to the $k$-th eigenvalue.